# How to find battery consuming part in application

Tags: android, performance, bluetooth, battery

I have a hybrid android application which using different features like vibration, WIFI,bluetooth etc. Recently i have made changes into WIFI locks which i need to keep available event phone goes into sleep mode as i want to do a streaming in background as well.

Currently i am facing a problem as phone battery started drain very quickly. I want to figure out how i can find out which part of application is very so long or taking too much CPU. I have tried DDMS tool to and use method profiling but result not showing anything interested here. I also tried battery historian but have no clue why my application consuming battery very quickly. Can someone tell me is there any other tool which i can used to figure out this problem?